# Resize a QGraphicsItem with the mouse

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

After putting a [rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aor5r.jpg) in a `QGraphicsScene` and making it movable with the mouse, how could I resize it with the mouse?

If no one knows an answer, a example could be good too, I'm developing in Python using `PyQt4`.

I know there are questions similar here, but they don't answer me respectively.

My simplified code:

```py
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

grview = QGraphicsView()
scene = QGraphicsScene()
scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 512, 512)

scene.addPixmap(QPixmap('01.png'))
grview.setScene(scene)

item = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 300, 150)

pen = QPen(Qt.darkMagenta)
pen.setWidth(4)
item.setPen(pen)

item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
scene.addItem(item)

grview.fitInView(scene.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

grview.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You would need to implement the resizing yourself. To do that you need to subclass `QGraphicsRectItem` and implement mouse event handlers: `mousePressEvent`, `mouseMoveEvent`, `mouseReleaseEvent`. 
The general idea is the following:

- You create a set of handles that you can use to resize the shape.
- By tracking handles position change you calculate the new geometry of the shape.

I wrote some code times ago which was perfectly working with PyQt5, but it should work with PyQt4 too. You should be able to adapt it to you needs:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QPointF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QPainterPath, QPainter, QColor, QPen, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsRectItem, QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem


class GraphicsRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):

    handleTopLeft = 1
    handleTopMiddle = 2
    handleTopRight = 3
    handleMiddleLeft = 4
    handleMiddleRight = 5
    handleBottomLeft = 6
    handleBottomMiddle = 7
    handleBottomRight = 8

    handleSize = +8.0
    handleSpace = -4.0

    handleCursors = {
        handleTopLeft: Qt.SizeFDiagCursor,
        handleTopMiddle: Qt.SizeVerCursor,
        handleTopRight: Qt.SizeBDiagCursor,
        handleMiddleLeft: Qt.SizeHorCursor,
        handleMiddleRight: Qt.SizeHorCursor,
        handleBottomLeft: Qt.SizeBDiagCursor,
        handleBottomMiddle: Qt.SizeVerCursor,
        handleBottomRight: Qt.SizeFDiagCursor,
    }

    def __init__(self, *args):
        """
        Initialize the shape.
        """
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.handles = {}
        self.handleSelected = None
        self.mousePressPos = None
        self.mousePressRect = None
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
        self.updateHandlesPos()

    def handleAt(self, point):
        """
        Returns the resize handle below the given point.
        """
        for k, v, in self.handles.items():
            if v.contains(point):
                return k
        return None

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, moveEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse moves over the shape (NOT PRESSED).
        """
        if self.isSelected():
            handle = self.handleAt(moveEvent.pos())
            cursor = Qt.ArrowCursor if handle is None else self.handleCursors[handle]
            self.setCursor(cursor)
        super().hoverMoveEvent(moveEvent)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, moveEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse leaves the shape (NOT PRESSED).
        """
        self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        super().hoverLeaveEvent(moveEvent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse is pressed on the item.
        """
        self.handleSelected = self.handleAt(mouseEvent.pos())
        if self.handleSelected:
            self.mousePressPos = mouseEvent.pos()
            self.mousePressRect = self.boundingRect()
        super().mousePressEvent(mouseEvent)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse is being moved over the item while being pressed.
        """
        if self.handleSelected is not None:
            self.interactiveResize(mouseEvent.pos())
        else:
            super().mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse is released from the item.
        """
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent)
        self.handleSelected = None
        self.mousePressPos = None
        self.mousePressRect = None
        self.update()

    def boundingRect(self):
        """
        Returns the bounding rect of the shape (including the resize handles).
        """
        o = self.handleSize + self.handleSpace
        return self.rect().adjusted(-o, -o, o, o)

    def updateHandlesPos(self):
        """
        Update current resize handles according to the shape size and position.
        """
        s = self.handleSize
        b = self.boundingRect()
        self.handles[self.handleTopLeft] = QRectF(b.left(), b.top(), s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleTopMiddle] = QRectF(b.center().x() - s / 2, b.top(), s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleTopRight] = QRectF(b.right() - s, b.top(), s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleMiddleLeft] = QRectF(b.left(), b.center().y() - s / 2, s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleMiddleRight] = QRectF(b.right() - s, b.center().y() - s / 2, s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleBottomLeft] = QRectF(b.left(), b.bottom() - s, s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleBottomMiddle] = QRectF(b.center().x() - s / 2, b.bottom() - s, s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleBottomRight] = QRectF(b.right() - s, b.bottom() - s, s, s)

    def interactiveResize(self, mousePos):
        """
        Perform shape interactive resize.
        """
        offset = self.handleSize + self.handleSpace
        boundingRect = self.boundingRect()
        rect = self.rect()
        diff = QPointF(0, 0)

        self.prepareGeometryChange()

        if self.handleSelected == self.handleTopLeft:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.left()
            fromY = self.mousePressRect.top()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setLeft(toX)
            boundingRect.setTop(toY)
            rect.setLeft(boundingRect.left() + offset)
            rect.setTop(boundingRect.top() + offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleTopMiddle:

            fromY = self.mousePressRect.top()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setTop(toY)
            rect.setTop(boundingRect.top() + offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleTopRight:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.right()
            fromY = self.mousePressRect.top()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setRight(toX)
            boundingRect.setTop(toY)
            rect.setRight(boundingRect.right() - offset)
            rect.setTop(boundingRect.top() + offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleMiddleLeft:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.left()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            boundingRect.setLeft(toX)
            rect.setLeft(boundingRect.left() + offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleMiddleRight:
            print("MR")
            fromX = self.mousePressRect.right()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            boundingRect.setRight(toX)
            rect.setRight(boundingRect.right() - offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleBottomLeft:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.left()
            fromY = self.mousePressRect.bottom()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setLeft(toX)
            boundingRect.setBottom(toY)
            rect.setLeft(boundingRect.left() + offset)
            rect.setBottom(boundingRect.bottom() - offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleBottomMiddle:

            fromY = self.mousePressRect.bottom()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setBottom(toY)
            rect.setBottom(boundingRect.bottom() - offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleBottomRight:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.right()
            fromY = self.mousePressRect.bottom()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setRight(toX)
            boundingRect.setBottom(toY)
            rect.setRight(boundingRect.right() - offset)
            rect.setBottom(boundingRect.bottom() - offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        self.updateHandlesPos()

    def shape(self):
        """
        Returns the shape of this item as a QPainterPath in local coordinates.
        """
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRect(self.rect())
        if self.isSelected():
            for shape in self.handles.values():
                path.addEllipse(shape)
        return path

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        """
        Paint the node in the graphic view.
        """
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 100)))
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0), 1.0, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 255)))
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0, 255), 1.0, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        for handle, rect in self.handles.items():
            if self.handleSelected is None or handle == self.handleSelected:
                painter.drawEllipse(rect)


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    grview = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 680, 459)

    scene.addPixmap(QPixmap('01.png'))
    grview.setScene(scene)

    item = GraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 300, 150)
    scene.addItem(item)

    grview.fitInView(scene.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    grview.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'right'`

Comment: Posting the traceback would help. Anyway I edited the code and it should work now.

Comment: I tried your code in PyQt5 and PyQt4, but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: You should provide a traceback or describe better what is not working because to me it works quite nice. Obviously you need to adapt the code to your specific environment.

Comment: I can't move it, so I added in the constructor `self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)`, but I can't resize it and the code doesn't generate erros. Could you provide the code how you use? Because I don't understando how it doesn't work here. I really need this functionality.

Comment: The problem was not in the class itself but I believe it was in the usage of the instance created (in case you were using the code provided in the question). I updated my answer providing also a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: This would be ideal if the user could not negatively resize the object. I noticed it causes all kinds of paint refresh issues when that happens. Can someone think of a nice way to fix that?

Comment: You could check the area of the rectangle to be always > 0 (while resizing) and when it goes to 0 you simply skip the resize.

Answer (score 5):

[Daniele's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34442054/4794) was very helpful, and I particularly like the resizing handles. I didn't like the fact that you could move the rectangle outside the window limits or resize it until it had negative width or height.

This code enforces bounds on the moving and resizing, so you can't cause those problems. I left off the resizing handles to keep this example simple.

```
import typing

from PySide6.QtCore import QRectF, QSize
from PySide6.QtGui import QPen, QBrush, QColor, QResizeEvent
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene,
                               QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsRectItem, QMainWindow,
                               QVBoxLayout, QWidget)


class ResizableRect(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setPen(QPen(QBrush(QColor('blue')), 5))
        self.selected_edge = None
        self.click_pos = self.click_rect = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """ The mouse is pressed, start tracking movement. """
        self.click_pos = event.pos()
        rect = self.rect()
        if abs(rect.left() - self.click_pos.x()) < 5:
            self.selected_edge = 'left'
        elif abs(rect.right() - self.click_pos.x()) < 5:
            self.selected_edge = 'right'
        elif abs(rect.top() - self.click_pos.y()) < 5:
            self.selected_edge = 'top'
        elif abs(rect.bottom() - self.click_pos.y()) < 5:
            self.selected_edge = 'bottom'
        else:
            self.selected_edge = None
        self.click_pos = event.pos()
        self.click_rect = rect
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """ Continue tracking movement while the mouse is pressed. """
        # Calculate how much the mouse has moved since the click.
        pos = event.pos()
        x_diff = pos.x() - self.click_pos.x()
        y_diff = pos.y() - self.click_pos.y()

        # Start with the rectangle as it was when clicked.
        rect = QRectF(self.click_rect)

        # Then adjust by the distance the mouse moved.
        if self.selected_edge is None:
            rect.translate(x_diff, y_diff)
        elif self.selected_edge == 'top':
            rect.adjust(0, y_diff, 0, 0)
        elif self.selected_edge == 'left':
            rect.adjust(x_diff, 0, 0, 0)
        elif self.selected_edge == 'bottom':
            rect.adjust(0, 0, 0, y_diff)
        elif self.selected_edge == 'right':
            rect.adjust(0, 0, x_diff, 0)

        # Figure out the limits of movement. I did it by updating the scene's
        # rect after the window resizes.
        scene_rect = self.scene().sceneRect()
        view_left = scene_rect.left()
        view_top = scene_rect.top()
        view_right = scene_rect.right()
        view_bottom = scene_rect.bottom()

        # Next, check if the rectangle has been dragged out of bounds.
        if rect.top() < view_top:
            if self.selected_edge is None:
                rect.translate(0, view_top-rect.top())
            else:
                rect.setTop(view_top)
        if rect.left() < view_left:
            if self.selected_edge is None:
                rect.translate(view_left-rect.left(), 0)
            else:
                rect.setLeft(view_left)
        if view_bottom < rect.bottom():
            if self.selected_edge is None:
                rect.translate(0, view_bottom - rect.bottom())
            else:
                rect.setBottom(view_bottom)
        if view_right < rect.right():
            if self.selected_edge is None:
                rect.translate(view_right - rect.right(), 0)
            else:
                rect.setRight(view_right)

        # Also check if the rectangle has been dragged inside out.
        if rect.width() < 5:
            if self.selected_edge == 'left':
                rect.setLeft(rect.right() - 5)
            else:
                rect.setRight(rect.left() + 5)
        if rect.height() < 5:
            if self.selected_edge == 'top':
                rect.setTop(rect.bottom() - 5)
            else:
                rect.setBottom(rect.top() + 5)

        # Finally, update the rect that is now guaranteed to stay in bounds.
        self.setRect(rect)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        self.rect = ResizableRect()
        scene = QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 300, 300)
        scene.addItem(self.rect)
        self.view = QGraphicsView(central)
        self.view.setScene(scene)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(central)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.old_size: typing.Optional[QSize] = None

    def show(self):
        super().show()
        self.resize_scene()

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QResizeEvent):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.resize_scene()

    def resize_scene(self):
        if not self.isVisible():
            # Viewport size isn't set yet, so calculation won't work.
            return
        size = self.view.maximumViewportSize()
        if self.old_size is None:
            new_rect = QRectF(size.width()/4, size.height()/4,
                              size.width()/2, size.height()/2)
        else:
            old_rect = QRectF(self.rect.rect())
            x_scale = size.width() / self.old_size.width()
            y_scale = size.height() / self.old_size.height()
            new_rect = QRectF(old_rect.left()*x_scale, old_rect.top()*y_scale,
                              old_rect.width()*x_scale, old_rect.height()*y_scale)
        self.rect.setRect(new_rect)
        self.view.scene().setSceneRect(0, 0, size.width(), size.height())
        self.old_size = size


def main():
    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    app.exec_()


main()
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also trying to do a similar task, except in my case I needed a reusable object that could inherit the parent item that needed to be resized. Here is an example of using this `Resizer` class to add a resize anchor to its parent QGraphicsRectItem.

The `Resizer` class inherits QGraphicsObject and reimplements the paint method. The `itemChange` method of `Resizer` emits a signal which is assigned to the `resize` method in the parent `Box` class. This in turn uses the position change information from the resizer to adjust the rect of the box.

This way, the resizer can be resused for other items as well, without having to re-implement mouse press/move/release events.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Box(QGraphicsRectItem):

    def __init__(self, position, rect=QRectF(0, 0, 100, 50), parent=None, scene=None):
        super().__init__(rect, parent, scene)

        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

        self.setPos(position)

        self.resizer = Resizer(parent=self)
        resizerWidth = self.resizer.rect.width() / 2
        resizerOffset = QPointF(resizerWidth, resizerWidth)
        self.resizer.setPos(self.rect().bottomRight() - resizerOffset)
        self.resizer.resizeSignal.connect(self.resize)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setColor(Qt.black)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.transparent)
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

    @pyqtSlot()
    def resize(self, change):
        self.setRect(self.rect().adjusted(0, 0, change.x(), change.y()))
        self.prepareGeometryChange()
        self.update()


class Resizer(QGraphicsObject):

    resizeSignal = pyqtSignal(QPointF)

    def __init__(self, rect=QRectF(0, 0, 10, 10), parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        self.rect = rect

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rect

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        if self.isSelected():
            pen = QPen()
            pen.setStyle(Qt.DotLine)
            painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawEllipse(self.rect)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange:
            if self.isSelected():
                self.resizeSignal.emit(value - self.pos())
        return value


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 1000)
    view.setScene(scene)

    box = Box(QPointF(50, 50), scene=scene)

    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying this with QGraphicsPixmapItem class, modifying the resizer class from @pbreach, this is what worked for me:

```
class Resizer(QGraphicsObject):
resizeSignal = pyqtSignal(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemChange,QPointF)
def __init__(self,rect = QRectF(0,0,10,10),parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable,True)
    self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable,True)
    self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges,True)
    self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
    self.rect = rect
    self.hide()

def boundingRect(self):
    return self.rect

def paint(self,painter,option,widget=None):
    if self.isSelected():
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setStyle(Qt.DotLine)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
    painter.drawEllipse(self.rect)
    self.update()

def itemChange(self,change,value):
    self.prepareGeometryChange()
    if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange:
        if self.isSelected():
            self.resizeSignal.emit(change,self.pos())
    return super(Resizer,self).itemChange(change,value)

'''END CLASS'''

class GraphicLayer(QGraphicsPixmapItem):
def __init__(self,top_left_x,top_left_y,graphic,rect=QRectF(0,0,100,100),parent=None,scene=None):
    super().__init__(parent=parent)
    self.rect = rect
    self.setPixmap(graphic)
    self.graphic = graphic
    self.mousePressPos = None
    self.mousePressRect = None
    self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
    self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable,True)
    self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable,True)
    self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges,True)
    self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable,True)
    self.setPos(top_left_x,top_left_y)

    # Resizer actions
    self.resizer = Resizer(parent=self)
    r_width = self.resizer.boundingRect().width() - 2
    self.r_offset = QPointF(r_width,r_width)
    self.resizer.setPos(self.boundingRect().bottomRight()-self.r_offset)
    self.resizer.resizeSignal.connect(self.resize)

def set_tag(self,item_id):
    self.tag = item_id

def get_tag(self):
    return self.tag

def hoverMoveEvent(self,event):
    if self.isSelected():
        self.resizer.show()
    else:
        self.resizer.hide()

def hoverLeave(self,event):
    self.resizer.hide()

@pyqtSlot()
def resize(self,change,value):
    pixmap = self.graphic.scaled(value.x(),value.y(),transformMode=Qt.SmoothTransformation)
    self.setPixmap(pixmap)
    self.prepareGeometryChange()
    self.update()

"""END OF CLASS"""
```

Here is a small gif of this class working. Important! This was done in PyQt5.

[image]

Please let me know your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

Here is mine with a less code :

```
class BoxItem(QGraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mousePressPos = None
        self.mousePressRect = None
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        # self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        # self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)

        self.rect = QRect(0, 0, 100, 100)

        self.moving = False
        self.origin = QPoint()

        # # Resizer actions
        # self.resizer.setPos(self.boundingRect().bottomRight() - self.r_offset)
        # self.resizer.resizeSignal.connect(self.resize)

    def corner_rect(self) -> QRect:
        """ Return corner rect geometry """
        return QRect(self.rect.right() - 10, self.rect.bottom() - 10, 10, 10)

    def boundingRect(self) -> QRectF:
        """ Override boundingRect """
        return self.rect.adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        """ OVerride paint  """

        brush = QBrush(QColor(255, 100, 100, 200))
        brush.setStyle(Qt.Dense7Pattern)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.drawRect(self.rect)

        if self.isSelected():
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt.red)))
            painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
            painter.drawRect(self.corner_rect())

            # Draw selection
            pen = QPen(QColor(Qt.green))
            pen.setStyle(Qt.DotLine)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.setBrush(Qt.NoBrush)
            painter.drawRect(self.rect)

        self.update()

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        """ Override hover move Event : Display cursor """

        if self.isSelected() & self.corner_rect().contains(event.pos().toPoint()):
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
        else:
            self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)

        super().hoverMoveEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        """ override mouse Press Event """
        if self.isSelected() & self.corner_rect().contains(
            QPoint(event.pos().toPoint())
        ):
            self.moving = True
            self.origin = self.rect.topLeft()
        else:
            super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        """ Override mouse release event """
        self.moving = False
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        """ Override mouse move event """
        if self.moving:
            # If moving is set from mousePressEvent , change geometry
            self.prepareGeometryChange()

            pos = event.pos().toPoint()

            if pos.x() >= self.origin.x():
                self.rect.setRight(pos.x())
            else:
                self.rect.setLeft(pos.x())

            if pos.y() >= self.origin.y():
                self.rect.setBottom(pos.y())
            else:
                self.rect.setTop(pos.y())
            self.rect = self.rect.normalized()
            self.update()
            return
        else:
            super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
```