# Resizing QGraphicsItem based on position of child 'resizer' item

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsitem

I'm trying to create a minimal QGraphicsItem that acts as a resizer to its parent. I think I'm nearly there but am drawing a blank and how to convey its position to the parent item when it is being moved. What I am going for looks something like this (without the text):

[image]

And here is a self contained example of what I have so far:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class Resizer(QGraphicsEllipseItem):

    def __init__(self, rect=QRectF(0, 0, 10, 10), parent=None, scene=None):
        super().__init__(rect, parent, scene)

        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        self.resize = True
        self.initialPos = self.scenePos()
        self.setSelected(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        if self.resize:
            self.currentPos = self.scenePos()
            self.change = self.initialPos - self.currentPos
        super().mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        self.resize = False
        self.setSelected(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
    view.setScene(scene)

    rect = QRectF(100, 100, 150, 50)
    box = QGraphicsRectItem(rect)

    scene.addItem(box)

    resizer = Resizer(parent=box)
    resizerWidth = resizer.rect().width() / 2
    resizerOffset = QPointF(resizerWidth, resizerWidth)
    resizer.setPos(box.rect().bottomRight() - resizerOffset)

    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So how can I convey `self.change` in the `mouseMoveEvent` to the parent in a way that the parent is resized as the `Resizer` is being moved? Any other suggestions are welcome.

I've tried converting the `Resizer` to a subclass of `QGraphicsObject` so that it could emit a signal on `mouseMoveEvent`, but `QGraphicsObject` does not have a paint method and I am unsure on how to display the `Resizer` on the scene.

Any advice on this is welcome.

Comment: @DanielePantaleone I somewhat agree. The way I solved it is a bit different though. I am posting my answer in case it could be useful.

Comment: Exactly. Posting a good solution to a dupe has it's own perks. But if you post it to the original question (if you are sure that it is a new merit-able answer) then you might get more views to that (older questions with more views index more on Google Search). Take note the next time.

Comment: @BhargavRao Great! Thanks for the advice - will post in orginal.

Comment: Don't do so now. Keep that in mind the next time.

Answer (score 1):

I ended converting the `Resizer` class to a subclass of `QGraphicsObject`. It turns out it was possible to reimplement the paint method (even though my auto-completion did not find it previously).

`Resizer.itemChange` now emits a signal which is assigned to the `resize` method in the parent `Box` class which uses the position change information from the resizer to adjust the rect of the box.

This way, the resizer can be resused for other items as well, without having to re-implement mouse press/move/release events as in the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429632/resize-a-qgraphicsitem-with-the-mouse/34442054#34442054).

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Box(QGraphicsRectItem):

    def __init__(self, position, rect=QRectF(0, 0, 100, 50), parent=None, scene=None):
        super().__init__(rect, parent, scene)

        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

        self.setPos(position)

        self.resizer = Resizer(parent=self)
        resizerWidth = self.resizer.rect.width() / 2
        resizerOffset = QPointF(resizerWidth, resizerWidth)
        self.resizer.setPos(self.rect().bottomRight() - resizerOffset)
        self.resizer.resizeSignal.connect(self.resize)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setColor(Qt.black)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.transparent)
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

    @pyqtSlot()
    def resize(self, change):
        self.setRect(self.rect().adjusted(0, 0, change.x(), change.y()))
        self.prepareGeometryChange()
        self.update()


class Resizer(QGraphicsObject):

    resizeSignal = pyqtSignal(QPointF)

    def __init__(self, rect=QRectF(0, 0, 10, 10), parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        self.rect = rect

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rect

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        if self.isSelected():
            pen = QPen()
            pen.setStyle(Qt.DotLine)
            painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawEllipse(self.rect)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange:
            if self.isSelected():
                self.resizeSignal.emit(value - self.pos())
        return value


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 1000)
    view.setScene(scene)

    box = Box(QPointF(50, 50), scene=scene)

    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```