# PyQt QGraphicsView Dark Area outside rectangle

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I need to create an adjustable selection rectangle for QgraphicsView, here is what I have at the moment : 
[image: PyQt Adjustable rectangle selection]

I subclassed QGraphicsRectItem object, added the handles and mouse actions, working pretty well! my code is inspired by this one : 
[Resize a QGraphicsItem with the mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429632/resize-a-qgraphicsitem-with-the-mouse/34442054)

Working current code example :

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class GraphicsRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):

    handleTopLeft = 1
    handleTopMiddle = 2
    handleTopRight = 3
    handleMiddleLeft = 4
    handleMiddleRight = 5
    handleBottomLeft = 6
    handleBottomMiddle = 7
    handleBottomRight = 8
    handleSpace = -4.0
    handleSize = 20

    handleCursors = {
        handleTopLeft: Qt.SizeFDiagCursor,
        handleTopMiddle: Qt.SizeVerCursor,
        handleTopRight: Qt.SizeBDiagCursor,
        handleMiddleLeft: Qt.SizeHorCursor,
        handleMiddleRight: Qt.SizeHorCursor,
        handleBottomLeft: Qt.SizeBDiagCursor,
        handleBottomMiddle: Qt.SizeVerCursor,
        handleBottomRight: Qt.SizeFDiagCursor,
    }

    def __init__(self, *args):
        """
        Initialize the shape.
        """
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.handles = {}
        self.handleSelected = None
        self.mousePressPos = None
        self.mousePressRect = None
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, False)


        self.updateHandlesPos()

    def handleAt(self, point):
        """
        Returns the resize handle below the given point.
        """
        for k, v, in self.handles.items():
            if v.contains(point):
                return k
        return None

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, moveEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse moves over the shape (NOT PRESSED).
        """
        if self.isSelected():
            handle = self.handleAt(moveEvent.pos())
            cursor = Qt.ArrowCursor if handle is None else self.handleCursors[handle]
            self.setCursor(cursor)
        super().hoverMoveEvent(moveEvent)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, moveEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse leaves the shape (NOT PRESSED).
        """
        self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        super().hoverLeaveEvent(moveEvent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse is pressed on the item.
        """

        self.handleSelected = self.handleAt(mouseEvent.pos())
        if self.handleSelected:
            self.mousePressPos = mouseEvent.pos()
            self.mousePressRect = self.boundingRect()
        super().mousePressEvent(mouseEvent)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse is being moved over the item while being pressed.
        """
        if self.handleSelected is not None:
            self.interactiveResize(mouseEvent.pos())
        else:
            super().mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse is released from the item.
        """
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent)
        self.handleSelected = None
        self.mousePressPos = None
        self.mousePressRect = None
        self.update()

    def boundingRect(self):
        """
        Returns the bounding rect of the shape (including the resize handles).
        """
        o = self.handleSize + self.handleSpace
        return self.rect().adjusted(-o, -o, o, o)

    def updateHandlesPos(self):
        """
        Update current resize handles according to the shape size and position.
        """
        s = self.handleSize
        b = self.boundingRect()
        self.handles[self.handleTopLeft] = QRectF(b.left(), b.top(), s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleTopMiddle] = QRectF(b.center().x() - s / 2, b.top(), s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleTopRight] = QRectF(b.right() - s, b.top(), s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleMiddleLeft] = QRectF(b.left(), b.center().y() - s / 2, s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleMiddleRight] = QRectF(b.right() - s, b.center().y() - s / 2, s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleBottomLeft] = QRectF(b.left(), b.bottom() - s, s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleBottomMiddle] = QRectF(b.center().x() - s / 2, b.bottom() - s, s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleBottomRight] = QRectF(b.right() - s, b.bottom() - s, s, s)

    def interactiveResize(self, mousePos):
        """
        Perform shape interactive resize.
        """
        offset = self.handleSize + self.handleSpace
        boundingRect = self.boundingRect()
        rect = self.rect()
        diff = QPointF(0, 0)

        self.prepareGeometryChange()

        if self.handleSelected == self.handleTopLeft:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.left()
            fromY = self.mousePressRect.top()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setLeft(toX)
            boundingRect.setTop(toY)
            rect.setLeft(boundingRect.left() + offset)
            rect.setTop(boundingRect.top() + offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleTopMiddle:

            fromY = self.mousePressRect.top()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setTop(toY)
            rect.setTop(boundingRect.top() + offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleTopRight:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.right()
            fromY = self.mousePressRect.top()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setRight(toX)
            boundingRect.setTop(toY)
            rect.setRight(boundingRect.right() - offset)
            rect.setTop(boundingRect.top() + offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleMiddleLeft:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.left()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            boundingRect.setLeft(toX)
            rect.setLeft(boundingRect.left() + offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleMiddleRight:
            # print("MR")
            fromX = self.mousePressRect.right()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            boundingRect.setRight(toX)
            rect.setRight(boundingRect.right() - offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleBottomLeft:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.left()
            fromY = self.mousePressRect.bottom()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setLeft(toX)
            boundingRect.setBottom(toY)
            rect.setLeft(boundingRect.left() + offset)
            rect.setBottom(boundingRect.bottom() - offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleBottomMiddle:

            fromY = self.mousePressRect.bottom()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setBottom(toY)
            rect.setBottom(boundingRect.bottom() - offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleBottomRight:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.right()
            fromY = self.mousePressRect.bottom()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setRight(toX)
            boundingRect.setBottom(toY)
            rect.setRight(boundingRect.right() - offset)
            rect.setBottom(boundingRect.bottom() - offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        self.updateHandlesPos()

    def shape(self):
        """
        Returns the shape of this item as a QPainterPath in local coordinates.
        """
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRect(self.rect())
        if self.isSelected():
            for shape in self.handles.values():
                path.addEllipse(shape)
        return path

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        """
        Paint the node in the graphic view.
        """
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 0)))
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(127, 127, 127), 2.0, Qt.DashLine))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(81, 168, 220, 200)))
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0, 255), 1.0, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        for handle, rect in self.handles.items():
            if self.handleSelected is None or handle == self.handleSelected:
                painter.drawRect(rect)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000)
    view.setScene(scene)
    box = GraphicsRectItem(100, 100, 200, 200)
    scene.addItem(box)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To make the selected area more visible, I'd like to make the area outside the rectangle darker, here is a quick photoshopped preview :

[image: Pyqt crop selection with darker outside]

Any Idea how to achieve that? I tried to add a semi-transparent Rectangle on top, it works, but is it possible to use my selection-rectangle item as "mask"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer I have not used the code you sample but I have translated [this project](http://%20https://github.com/cesarbs/sizegripitem) from C ++ to Python since it has the advantage that you can add a resizer without modifying a custom code, the only requirement is that the item must to have a method `rect()` and `setRect()` that allows us to resize some feature.

As I see the item you want to use to select an internal section of a `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, then I will create the `CropItem` class that has an internal gap that will be handled by the `SizeGripItem` as shown below:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor, QPen, QPixmap, QPainterPath, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsPathItem, QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene


class HandleItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, position_flags, parent):
        QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, -10, -10, 20, 20, parent)
        self._positionFlags = position_flags

        self.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(81, 168, 220, 200)))
        self.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0, 255), 1.0, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        self.setFlag(self.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(self.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)

    def positionflags(self):
        return self._positionFlags

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        retVal = value
        if change == self.ItemPositionChange:
            retVal = self.restrictPosition(value)
        elif change == self.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            pos = value
            if self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.TopLeft:
                self.parentItem().setTopLeft(pos)
            elif self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.Top:
                self.parentItem().setTop(pos.y())
            elif self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.TopRight:
                self.parentItem().setTopRight(pos)
            elif self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.Right:
                self.parentItem().setRight(pos.x())
            elif self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.BottomRight:
                self.parentItem().setBottomRight(pos)
            elif self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.Bottom:
                self.parentItem().setBottom(pos.y())
            elif self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.BottomLeft:
                self.parentItem().setBottomLeft(pos)
            elif self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.Left:
                self.parentItem().setLeft(pos.x())
        return retVal

    def restrictPosition(self, newPos):
        retVal = self.pos()

        if self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Top or self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Bottom:
            retVal.setY(newPos.y())

        if self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Left or self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Right:
            retVal.setX(newPos.x())

        if self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Top and retVal.y() > self.parentItem()._rect.bottom():
            retVal.setY(self.parentItem()._rect.bottom())

        elif self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Bottom and retVal.y() < self.parentItem()._rect.top():
            retVal.setY(self.parentItem()._rect.top())

        if self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Left and retVal.x() > self.parentItem()._rect.right():
            retVal.setX(self.parentItem()._rect.right())

        elif self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Right and retVal.x() < self.parentItem()._rect.left():
            retVal.setX(self.parentItem()._rect.left())

        return retVal


class SizeGripItem(QGraphicsItem):
    Top = 0x01
    Bottom = 0x1 << 1
    Left = 0x1 << 2
    Right = 0x1 << 3
    TopLeft = Top | Left
    BottomLeft = Bottom | Left
    TopRight = Top | Right
    BottomRight = Bottom | Right

    handleCursors = {
        TopLeft: Qt.SizeFDiagCursor,
        Top: Qt.SizeVerCursor,
        TopRight: Qt.SizeBDiagCursor,
        Left: Qt.SizeHorCursor,
        Right: Qt.SizeHorCursor,
        BottomLeft: Qt.SizeBDiagCursor,
        Bottom: Qt.SizeVerCursor,
        BottomRight: Qt.SizeFDiagCursor,
    }

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QGraphicsItem.__init__(self, parent)
        self._handleItems = []

        self._rect = QRectF(0, 0, 0, 0)
        if self.parentItem():
            self._rect = self.parentItem().rect()

        for flag in (self.TopLeft, self.Top, self.TopRight, self.Right,
                     self.BottomRight, self.Bottom, self.BottomLeft, self.Left):
            handle = HandleItem(flag, self)
            handle.setCursor(self.handleCursors[flag])
            self._handleItems.append(handle)

        self.updateHandleItemPositions()

    def boundingRect(self):
        if self.parentItem():
            return self._rect
        else:
            return QRectF(0, 0, 0, 0)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(127, 127, 127), 2.0, Qt.DashLine))
        painter.drawRect(self._rect)

    def doResize(self):
        self.parentItem().setRect(self._rect)
        self.updateHandleItemPositions()

    def updateHandleItemPositions(self):
        for item in self._handleItems:
            item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, False)

            if item.positionflags() == self.TopLeft:
                item.setPos(self._rect.topLeft())
            elif item.positionflags() == self.Top:
                item.setPos(self._rect.left() + self._rect.width() / 2 - 1,
                            self._rect.top())
            elif item.positionflags() == self.TopRight:
                item.setPos(self._rect.topRight())
            elif item.positionflags() == self.Right:
                item.setPos(self._rect.right(),
                            self._rect.top() + self._rect.height() / 2 - 1)
            elif item.positionflags() == self.BottomRight:
                item.setPos(self._rect.bottomRight())
            elif item.positionflags() == self.Bottom:
                item.setPos(self._rect.left() + self._rect.width() / 2 - 1,
                            self._rect.bottom())
            elif item.positionflags() == self.BottomLeft:
                item.setPos(self._rect.bottomLeft())
            elif item.positionflags() == self.Left:
                item.setPos(self._rect.left(),
                            self._rect.top() + self._rect.height() / 2 - 1)
            item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

    def setTop(self, v):
        self._rect.setTop(v)
        self.doResize()

    def setRight(self, v):
        self._rect.setRight(v)
        self.doResize()

    def setBottom(self, v):
        self._rect.setBottom(v)
        self.doResize()

    def setLeft(self, v):
        self._rect.setLeft(v)
        self.doResize()

    def setTopLeft(self, v):
        self._rect.setTopLeft(v)
        self.doResize()

    def setTopRight(self, v):
        self._rect.setTopRight(v)
        self.doResize()

    def setBottomRight(self, v):
        self._rect.setBottomRight(v)
        self.doResize()

    def setBottomLeft(self, v):
        self._rect.setBottomLeft(v)
        self.doResize()

class CropItem(QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QGraphicsPathItem.__init__(self, parent)
        self.extern_rect = parent.boundingRect()
        self.intern_rect = QRectF(0, 0, self.extern_rect.width()/2, self.extern_rect.height()/2)
        self.intern_rect.moveCenter(self.extern_rect.center())
        self.setBrush(QColor(10, 100, 100, 100))
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.NoPen))
        SizeGripItem(self)
        self.create_path()

    def create_path(self):
        self._path = QPainterPath()
        self._path.addRect(self.extern_rect)
        self._path.moveTo(self.intern_rect.topLeft())
        self._path.addRect(self.intern_rect)
        self.setPath(self._path)


    def rect(self):
        return self.intern_rect

    def setRect(self, rect):
        self._intern = rect
        self.create_path()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    view.setScene(scene)
    pixmapItem = scene.addPixmap(QPixmap("Lenna.png"))
    cropItem = CropItem(pixmapItem)
    view.fitInView(scene.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

    view.show()
    view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    view.setFixedSize(view.size())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]